# How to get every item inside a listbox in tkinter?

Tags: python, tkinter

How do I make it so that I get all the items inside a listbox into a variable? I only manage to get the last item only. I want to print the items of a listbox into a new window but I only print the last item only.

```
  get_content = listbox2.get(0, END)
            bb = Label(receipt_window, text = "Pizzeria")
            line1 = Label(receipt_window, text = "----------------------------------------------------------------")
            for con_item in get_content:
                con = (con_item.split('PHP'))
                con1 = con[0]
                con2 = con[1]
                rec_content = f'{con1:<40}costs PHP{con2:<8}'
                receipt = Label(receipt_window, text = rec_content)
            bb.pack()
            line1.pack()
            receipt.pack()
```

The listbox contains:
[image: Listbox Content]

The result:
[image: result]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is because you use same variable `receipt` for the labels created inside the for loop and call `receipt.pack()` outside the for loop, so the last label created inside for loop will be *packed* only.

You need to call `receipt.pack()` inside the for loop:

```py
    get_content = listbox2.get(0, END)
    bb = Label(receipt_window, text='Pizzeria')
    line1 = Label(receipt_window, text='----------------------------------------------------------------')
    bb.pack()
    line1.pack()
    for con_item in get_content:
        con1, con2 = con_item.split('PHP')
        rec_content = f'{con1:<40}costs PHP{con2:<8}'
        receipt = Label(receipt_window, text=rec_content)
        receipt.pack()
```

Note that it is better to use fixed width (monospaced) font for the labels.